# Why is ^M being returned when I press enter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal

Every once in a while in Rails I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and rather than submitting as normal, it adds `^M` to the line.

In my current example:

```
Overwrite /Users/bc/Dropbox/test_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] ^M
```

Tried searching for this problem all over with no luck. It's more of a minor annoyance than a problem but I'd like to be able to stop it without restarting my terminal. Thanks!

Comment: I know ctrl+enter replaces pressing enter in this scenario, but I don't know what causes it either, and would love to know.

Comment: Happens to me all the time.. I always though it had to do with ncurses but never looked into it

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a problem with the stty terminal line setting. Try running in your terminar `stty sane` and says us if that fixes it.